# Jekyll portfolio with Github pages

Tags: github, jekyll

I have an existing site that is in Jekyll and I'd like to add in to Github pages. At the moment I'm copying & pasting each file after running `jekyll build` and then pushing that up to Github. Is there a way I can remove the copying and pasting part and just commit the site. I'm not sure how Github pages would handle the site builds files and folders to only display what's inside the _site folder.

The current Jekyll structure is:
[image: Jekyll site structure]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If your site works with github-pages gem, then you just need to commit all the files without the `_site` folder to Github.

Github will detect your site and generate it, read more here: https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-as-a-static-site-generator-with-github-pages/